# Newbie on use of recursion in Groovy/traverse tree?

Tags: recursion, groovy

In our current application we have a need to traverse down a tree and capture all operators on a specific device (and child devices). A device could have child devices with also specific operators on it.

As i am new to the use of recursion in Groovy i am wondering if i am doing things right..?
Any pointer to help me learn better ways of doing things?

```
def listOperators(device) {
    // list with all operator id's
    def results = []

    // closure to traverse down the tree
    def getAllOperators = { aDevice->
        if(aDevice) {
            aDevice.operators.each { it ->
                results << it.id
            }
        }
        if (aDevice?.children) {
            aDevice.children.each { child ->
                results << owner.call(child)
            }
        }
    }

    // call the closure with the given device
    getAllOperators(device)

    // return list with unique results
    return results.unique()
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple things to note:

- Doing the recursive call through `owner` is not a good idea.  The definition of `owner` changes if the call is nested within another closure.  It's error prone and has no advantages over just using the name.  When the closure is a local variable, split its up the declaration and definition of the closure so the name is in scope.  E.g.:

  `def getAllOperators`
  `getAllOperators = { ...`
- You are appending the operators to a result list outside the recursive closure.  But you are also appending the result of each recursive call to the same list.  Either append to the list *or* store the results from each recursive call, but not both.

Here's a simpler alternative:

```
def listOperators(device) {
    def results = []
    if (device) {
        results += device.operators*.id
        device.children?.each { child ->
            results += listOperators(child)
        }
    }
    results.unique()
}
```